# WAMP server PhpMyAdmin not authenticating with valid credentials

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

WAMP server MySQL is working fine in CLI. But **PHPMyAdmin is not working**. I had MySQL and workbench installed with **3306** port (before I install the WAMP server). This is why My WAMP server MySQL wasn't working, I changed the port to **3309** in MySQL my.ini file, it's working fine in CLI but not working in PHPMyAdmin.

I have already tried `alter user 'username'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password';` still not working in with PHPMyAdmin but CLI. I don't want to downgrade my MySQL version.

*MySQL Version 8.0.21*

ERROR:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean not working? you can access phpmyadmin in the browser? meaning your apache is not running if that's the case, make sure that it's running port 80 is in used by apache

Comment: Do you need 2 instances of MySQL on your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must have 2 MySQL instances running then use the features built into WAMPServer to amend the MySQL port number

RIGHT Click on the WAMPServer icon in the system tray and click the TOOLS menu item

See below, then click on "Use port other than 3306" and WAMPServer will update ALL the required files so that you can use a non standard port for MySQL

[image]

Comment: It worked. You save my life, 10000 Thanks :)

Comment: But it makes another problem. https://imgur.com/608aRwJ     When I click the tray icon (left click) Is shows NO default DBMS...   I can't connect my project with MYSQL :

Comment: It woudl be simpler to backup your old databases and then uninstall the OTHER MySQL instance and the use the defaults again in WAMPServer

Comment: Possibly maybe, You know it's not a good practice, right?

Comment: What did you mean by "OTHER MYSQL instance"? Main MySQL server with workbench? or wamp server MySQL?

Comment: The instance you had installed before you installed another environment that has a MySQL server instance in it as well

Comment: You dont have to uninstall WorkBench, just the original MySQL Server instance. **After backing up any DB's you want to keep of course**

Comment: You know I am confused. Can you please tell me exactly what I have to do? (Sorry for wasting your time)

Comment: I got it. Let me try it plz

Comment: Uninstall the original instance of MySQL that came with Workbench. AFter backup. To get back to the old MySQL, stop WAMPServer. its quite possible that the original MySQL is what you are actually talking to unless you manually stopped it, as the version that comes with Workbench gets started at boot time automatically

Comment: It works as expected. Thank you RiggsFolly for your time. ( There's a lot of people knows the answer, most of them don't have time to help )

Answer (score 1):

Search for `libraries/config.default.php`

and change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']
```

it should be empty default is 3306 and add 3309

Addinally you have to run the installer again

- executing the install file
- select "Reconfigure" over the mysql server
- In Authentication Method tab, select "Use Legacy Authentication

Method"

Comment: i have add ed the part where you have also to reconfigure the mysql server

Comment: Maybe it's also the right answer. But it's a bit more hard for me as a beginner, I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose at the beginning the MariaDB server and on username type root, and password remains empty, after once you will be connected with Maria Db, switcher to MySQL ,
[screenswitcherserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMBI2.png)
and do the same thing side username and password